# How to make a `SELECT .... WHERE EXISTS` query with diesel?

Tags: rust, rust-diesel

Assuming I have a master entity (let's have it be a user) and a detail entity (let's go with adresses), how can I filter the master entity over values from its details?

Going with the user/address example, let's say we want to find all users who have an address in Berlin. In SQL, the query would probably be something like this:

```sql
SELECT * FROM user AS u
WHERE EXISTS(
    SELECT 0 FROM address AS a
    WHERE a.user_id = u.id
        AND a.city = 'Berlin'
)
```

To make this query in SQL, one has to use an alias (`user AS u`) and use it later in the `a.user_id = u.id` part. Is it possible to do something similar in diesel?

---

EDIT: I'm using diesel 2.0, rust 1.64 and here's the relevant section from `schema.rs`:

```rust
diesel::table! {
    addresses (id) {
        id -> Int4,
        user_id -> Int4,
        city -> Nullable<Varchar>,
    }
}

diesel::table! {
    users (id) {
        id -> Int4,
        name -> Varchar,
    }
}

diesel::joinable!(addresses -> users (user_id));

diesel::allow_tables_to_appear_in_same_query!(
    addresses,
    users,
);
```

Comment: Your question is incomplete. Please add at least the following information: 
* Your diesel version
* Your rust version
* The relevant part of your `schema.rs` file

Comment: I wouldn't have guessed, since versions wouldn't matter in the EF world which I'm more used to. Let me do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this specific query the usage of an alias is not required as each table appears exactly once in the query. Generally speaking: diesel does provide an [`alias!` macro](https://docs.diesel.rs/master/diesel/macro.alias.html), which allows to define table aliases for later use.

As for the corresponding query: Such queries are more or less literally translated to diesel dsl using the provided functions:

```rust
let sub_query = addresses::table
    .select(0.into_sql::<diesel::sql_types::Integer>())
    .filter(addresses::user_id.eq(users::id))
    .filter(addresses::city.eq("Berlin"));
let result = users::table.filter(diesel::dsl::exists(sub_query)).load::<CompatibleType>(&mut conn)?;
```